# Incurring in segmentation fault problems with doubly linked lists in C

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to insert nodes at the front of a doubly linked list using a function, but I get a segmentation fault error and just can't understand what the problem is. For the typedefing of the pointers I actually know I shouldn't do that, but my teacher asked me to typedef them, for who knows what reason.

Here is the code:

```
void insertInList(lista_char *pl){
    char charSel[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'e'};
    lista_char new_node = makesNode();

    new_node->info = charSel[rand()%10]; 

    new_node->next = *pl;
    new_node->prev = NULL;

    if(*pl != NULL)
        (*pl)->prev = new_node;

    *pl = new_node;
}
```

Comment: @ssd Inside that function there is only one instruction : `return (lista_char)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo_char));`

Comment: Ok... I think you'd better pass the address with a double star; i.e. `(lista_char **pl)`.

Comment: @ssd it looks as though `lista_char` is `typedef`ed as a pointer, from `lista_char new_node = makesNode();`

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, it's like that. I also wrote that in the body of the question...

Comment: You are dereferencing with `if(*pl != NULL)` but suppose it's the head of an empty list and `pl == NULL`? It might be easier to follow it you only `typedef` the pointer *after* the code is working. Teacher doesn't have to know that.

Comment: @WeatherVane You're right. I think I'll do an else to allow the insert when the list is empty. It probably was the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, a pointer with a double star will work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct lista_char {
  char info;
  struct lista_char *next;
  struct lista_char *prev;
} lista_char;

lista_char *makesNode()
{
  lista_char *node = malloc(sizeof(lista_char));
  return (node);
}

void insertInList(lista_char **pl)
{
  char charSel[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'e'};
  lista_char *new_node = makesNode();

  new_node->info = charSel[rand() % 10];
  new_node->next = *pl;
  new_node->prev = NULL;

  printf("%c\n", new_node->info);

  if (*pl != NULL)
    (*pl)->prev = new_node;

  *pl = new_node;
}

int main()
{
  lista_char *temp;
  lista_char *head = NULL;

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    insertInList(&head);
  }

  temp = head;

  while (temp->next) {
    if (temp->prev == NULL) {
      printf("prev: %c this: %c next: %c\n", '-', temp->info, (temp->next)->info);
    }
    else {
      printf("prev: %c this: %c next: %c\n", (temp->prev)->info, temp->info, (temp->next)->info);
    }

    temp = temp->next;
  }

  printf("prev: %c this: %c next: %c\n", (temp->prev)->info, temp->info, '-');

  // free memory
  temp = head;

  while (temp->next) {
    temp = temp->next;
    free(temp->prev);
  }

  free(temp);

  return 0;
}
```